# mosquitto-clients installation command not working on linux server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mosquitto

I am trying installing mosquitto-clients on my Linux local computer. I am using below command to install mosquitto-clients.

```
sudo yum install mosquitto mosquitto-clients
```

Output in commandline:

```
[root@ip-172-31-40-6 ec2-user]# sudo yum install mosquitto mosquitto-clients
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
824 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mosquitto.x86_64 0:1.5.8-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit) for package: mosquitto-1.5.8-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mosquitto-1.5.8-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mosquitto-1.5.8-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: mosquitto-1.5.8-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package mosquitto-clients.x86_64 0:1.5.5-1.4 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mosquitto-1.5.8-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: mosquitto-1.5.8-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit)
Error: Package: mosquitto-1.5.8-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: systemd
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@ip-172-31-40-6 ec2-user]#
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That is failing to install the `mosquitto` package not the `mosquitto-client` package.

Comment: Yes, let me know the reason behind it.

Comment: The question is says you are trying to install the clients, so have you tried just installing the clients package. (assuming you don't need the broker, as your question implies)

Comment: I am facing the same problem, if you found the solution, help me out here!